# using a variable as xquery sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have a query in sql as following

```
select  PricingXML.query('/Fields/Field1,/Fields/Field2') from T_SMPricingData
```

PricingXML is a xml column in the table T_SMPricingData.

I need to pass the xquery from a variable to the query like the following

```
declare @var nvarchar(100)
set @var='/Fields/Field1,/Fields/Field2'
select  PricingXML.query('sql:variable("@var")') from T_SMPricingData
```

How can I use the variable correctly. It is not working in the intended manner

**Edit**
 My output for the original correct query is

```
<Field1>10</Field1><Field2>11</Field2>
<Field1>20</Field1>
```

The data in the column looks like

```
<Fields>
<Field1>20</Field1>
<Field3>22</Field3>
<Field4>23</Field4>
</Fields>
```

Link for sql fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12d7c/6/0

Comment: I am not looking for values instead I am looking for specific nodes.

Comment: Can I query for multiple nodes from the xml

Comment: But I am getting the intended result, see my edit

Comment: Sure it is, as [constructed by rule 31 of the XQuery grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-Expr).

Comment: "Not working in the intended manner" is a really bad problem description. Actually, you're not even describing the intended manner. Please post example input, current and expected output. As you're using SQL Server, best would be to create a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12d7c/6/0

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the variable contains the path you want to retrieve?

Comment: yes the variable contains the many fields/ paths which I want to query. I want to convert that into a Stored Procedure

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52784/discussion-between-puneet-and-jens-erat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the above by

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(100)
SET @var='/Fields/Field1,/Fields/Field2'
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT PricingXml.query('''+@var+''') from MyTable'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```